# Combine features in Machine Learning KNN

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system, k-nn, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a simple **book recommendation system**, where I don't have any kind of ratings (no comments, no likes, no 1-5 stars, ...).

The information I can use is the following:

- Book metadata  :  title, author, published date, model (printed or
  ebook), genres (one or more).
- Username.
- Type : category of interaction made by a user, it can be 'order' (if the user ordered the book) or 'access' (if the user just checked the book).
- Number : if 'type' = 'access' then this parameter indicates the number of times the user accessed the book.

So I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
    number       type   username  product  price        model publishing_dt          genres
0        6     access   kerrigan     2345  12.99  printedbook    2020-02-01    fantasy,kids
1        4     access   kerrigan      897  14.95  printedbook    2019-03-05         fantasy
2        1  orderline  45michael    86833   2.65        ebook    2020-02-04      action,war 
3        1  orderline   kerrigan    86833   2.65        ebook    2020-02-04      action,war
```

My goal is to **develop a KNN system** to make book recommendations and I can have two types of classifications:

- Item-based : similarity between books (by genre and author).
- User-based : similarity between users. Take each user purchases and compare them to other users to find similarities so if *userA* bought *book1*, *book2* and *book3* and *userB* bought *book1*, *book2* and *book4* you can assume that *book3* is a good recommendation for *userB*.

But my doubt here is if I can develop a KNN system **combining** both technics, so depending on the data I input to it, it decides which solution is the better one.

Is this possible? Can someone point me in a good direction or send me some good tutorials?

EDIT - There are **three** scenarios:

1. The user is **logged in** and there's **enough** purchase history information.
2. The user is **logged in** but he/she is either new or **there's not enough**
   purchase history information.
3. The user is **not logged in**.

Desired output:

1. A combination of purchase history and book features (this is the case I don't know how to approach), it should take into account both the book features and the past purchases, maybe it would be a good choice to perform two searches instead of trying to make one.
2. As there's not enough purchase history information, here the best
   approach would be to just use book features to make a
   recommendation.
3. Same case as before.

Comment: "depending on the data I input to it, it decides which solution is the better one.", can you give an example of what kind of behaviour you would like to have?

Comment: See this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63687/recommend-another-product-only-on-purchase-history-of-users-available/63689#63689, you need Content-based models. As mentioned, I have implemented using such model using a combination of those resources. I might be able to make the polished notebook I have later (at the moment the tutorial contains private data), but said that you should be able to make something out of them.

Comment: @ValentinCalomme I've added an edit, I don't know if it helps to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TwinPenguins I've checked the answer and I think what I'm searching is a combination of both content-based models and collaborative models, as I would like to take into account the purchase history of the user, what I don't know is how to mix both things into one recommender.

Comment: @TwinPenguins one thing I've noticed is that when I try to check recsys.py on the answer you've sent me it takes me to this image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWFfC.png]

Comment: @Sara Thanks for the note for the recsys.py link, I just fixed it. Oh you have the purchase history, sure then you need to combine them, thus you need Hybrid Recommenders. Deep Matrix Factorization that I explained in that post would make it easier to do that, and it quite powerful to combine many features at the same time. I have it implemented for my own use case, in case you are wondering, so it is feasible.

Comment: @TwinPenguins I was checking the notebook you've linked on that answer but the results for recommendations based on 'Toy Story' don't seem quite good.

Comment: @Sara Why do you mean they are not good? What metrics? That is just a toy example. And that is just a col-filtering based on MF, not hybrid and DMF!