# What is the best model for a recommendation system using implicit ratings?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, recommender-system, python-3.x, matrix-factorisation

I have a similariy matrix that looks like this:

[image]

I have a bunch of user vectors with 1s and 0s, with a 1 indicating that someone has clicked on an email (as part of a campaign) and zero to indicate they haven't. Implicit ratings as I have come to understand them.

In terms of an approach, after researching different options, it would appear that the best algorithm to start with a is a matrix-factorisation approach. My question is: what is the best algorithm to start as a baseline model for this type of problem? Any advice on potential pitfalls. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the contents of the mails?

Comment: I've got a headline and a short snippet of text. It would be more accurate to describe this as links clicked within an email.

Comment: If you have the content of each email, you can have self attention approahces that have better performance.

Comment: Have you got an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after a baseline model, which I also strongly recommend, matrix-factorization (MF) approach (aka collaborative models) you mentioned is the most basic one and super fast and easy to implement. Then you can explore others like content-based models or hybrid recommenders, or even the recent ones based on the self-attention mechanism that Media mentioned. Doing this would give you something to compare with during A/B tests, if there is nothing is in place already. Just note that with the traditional MF may run into memory/performance issues if your matrix get very big (well, if your resources are limited!), and for that Deep Matrix Factorization are a better equivalent choice.

I have summarized almost a year ago about these three starting recommendation engines, see [**this answer**](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63687/recommend-another-product-only-on-purchase-history-of-users-available/63689#63689). I have code snippers/notebooks gathered from references there for practical implementation of these few baseline that might be able to share if needed.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for your case, but I believe you can employ approaches that are based on the self-attention mechanism. There numerous studies that show they perform better than the latent outcomes that can be achieved with SVD. For instance, you can see the paper of [SAIN](https://github.com/seongjunyun/SAIN) which its code is also open source. In the paper, you can see that they have shown their approach has better performance than SVD and usual self-attention mechanisim. By the way, it is based on self-attention.

If I want to summarize the method, it uses the contents of the products and the items and finds the interactions between the words, and it outputs the score that a user may assign to a product. It has good performance.

Due to the fact that you have the contents of mails, this approach may help you.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful